# usage of Text::Wrap:wrap() reducing the spaces at the beginning of the line

Tags: perl

I would like to restrict the column number to 45 characters. I am using the Text::Wrap:wrap as below.

```
$Text::Wrap::columns = 44;
print FOUT wrap('','' ,<FIN>);
```

It is making all the columns to 44 chars without work breakage. But it is reducing spaces for some of the lines at the beginning.

For example: Before using the `wrap()`, if a line has 5 spaces at the beginning, after using the `wrap()`, the spaces becoming 3.

Can any one please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this in Text::Wrap's POD documentation:

> `Text::Wrap::wrap()` starts its work by expanding all the tabs in its input into spaces. The last thing it does it to turn spaces back into tabs. If you do not want tabs in your results, set `$Text::Wrap::unexpand` to a false value. Likewise if you do not want to use 8-character tabstops, set `$Text::Wrap::tabstop` to the number of characters you do want for your tabstops.

This may explain the removal of spaces to tabs at the beginning of your line. You need to play around with `$Text::Wrap::tabstop` and `$Text::Wrap::unexpand` to see if this gets you the results you want.

You might want to try [Text::Format](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aFormat) or [Text::Wrapper](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aWrapper).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, Text::Wrap is ( not unreasonably ) removing extra whitespace at the front of the strings.  You do not want it to happen

Here is a solution for substituting spaces at the front of lines with underscores, running it through wrap() and then removing the underscores

```
use Text::Wrap;

#test data, note the 5 spaces at the start of some lines
for (1..4) { push @a,"     hello I love you", "Won't you tell me your name? ";} 
push @a,"She's walking down the street","     Blind to every eye she meets","Do you think you\'ll be the guy", "To make the queen of the angels sigh?";

#make it longer with repeating
push @b,@a,@a,@a;

$Text::Wrap::columns = 44;

#show bad behaviour
print "VERSION 1\n";
print wrap("","",@b);

#fixup strings with leading underscores
map {s/^\s+/"_" x length(\1)/e} @b;

@z=wrap("","",@b);

#remove _
map{s/_+/" " x length(\1)/ge} @z;
print "\nVERSION 2\n";
print @z;
```